Google play receipt validation api authentication error
I am currently trying to use spring boot for java to verify google play receipts. Functions such as viewing all subscription payments of registered apps work normally, but when I try to verify receipts, it only says that I do not have permission. What should I do? I gave owner rights in gcp and administrator rights to the service account in google play console. Also, I understand that the api access page has disappeared from the google play console recently.
type java

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisher;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisherScopes;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class GoogleConfig {
  @Bean
  public GoogleCredentials googleCredentials() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/firebase/hanstylesoft-8446e3d19866.json");
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)
            .createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));

    AccessToken accessToken = googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken();
    // Fetch access token
    googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();

    if (accessToken != null) {
      log.info("Access Token: {}", accessToken.getTokenValue());
      log.info("Token Expiry: {}", accessToken.getExpirationTime());
    }

    return googleCredentials;
  }

  @Bean
  public AndroidPublisher androidPublisher(GoogleCredentials credentials) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    return new AndroidPublisher.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)
    ).setApplicationName("packageName").build();
  }
}

type java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PurchaseServiceImpl implements PurchaseService {

 private final AndroidPublisher androidPublisher;

  @Override
  public ListSubscriptionsResponse getSubscriptionListForGoogle(String packageName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    AndroidPublisher.Monetization.Subscriptions.List request = androidPublisher.monetization().subscriptions().list(packageName);
    return request.execute();
  }

  @Override
  public SubscriptionPurchaseV2 verifyReceiptForGoogle(String packageName, String productId, String purchaseToken) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
      AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptionsv2.Get request = androidPublisher.purchases().subscriptionsv2().get(packageName, purchaseToken);
      return request.execute();
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      log.error("GoogleJsonResponseException: {}", e);
      return null;
    }
  }

type json
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "androidpublisher",
      "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
      "reason": "permissionDenied"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
}

